# How to search for a matching string in a file bottom-to-top without using tac?

Tags: shell, grep

I need to grep through a file, starting at the bottom of the file until I get to the first date that appears "2021-04-04", and then return that date. I don't want to start from the top and work my way down to the first line as there's thousands of lines in each file.

Example file contents:

```
random text on first line
random text on second line
2021-01-01
random text on fourth line
2021-02-03
random text on sixth line
2021-03-03
2021-04-04
Random text on ninth line
```

`tac` isn't available on MacOS so I can't use it.

Comment: There is no tool to search starting from the bottom of a file, and reversing the file first so you can then start searching from the top won't make the overall time taken any less for a file that's only thousands of lines long and will make it take longer when the last occurrence of the string you're searching for happens to be near the start of the file. Once you get into 10s of millions of lines then that might be worth considering and profiling before implementing.

Comment: You might want to install Homebrew (https://brew.sh) so that you can install all the GNU goodies, including a recent bash version.

Answer (score 2):

"thousands of lines" are nothing, they'll be processed in the blink of an eye. Once you get into 10s of millions of lines THEN you could start thinking about a performance improvement if it became necessary.

All you need is:

```
awk '/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/{line=$0} END{if (line!="") print line}' file
```

Here's the 3rd-run timing comparison for finding the last line containing 2 or more consecutive `5s` in a 100000 line file generated by `seq 100000 > file100k`, i.e. where the target string is just 45 lines from the end of the input file, with and without `tac`:

```
$ time awk '/5{2}/{line=$0} END{if (line!="") print line}' file100k
99955

real    0m0.056s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time tac file100k | awk '/5{2}/{print; exit}'
99955

real    0m0.056s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.030s
```

As you can see, both ran in a fraction of a second and using `tac` did nothing to improve the speed of execution. Switching to tac+grep doesn't make it any faster either, it still just takes 1/20th of a second:

```
$ time tac file100k | grep -m1 '5\{2\}'
99955

real    0m0.057s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s
```

In case you ever do need it in future, though, here's how to implement an efficient `tac` if you don't have it:

```
$ mytac() { cat -n "${@:--}" | sort -k1,1rn | cut -d$'\t' -f2-; }
```

```
$ seq 5 | mytac
5
4
3
2
1
```

The above `mytac()` function just adds line numbers to the input, sorts those in reverse and then removes them again. If your `cat` doesn't have `-n` to add line numbers then you can use `nl` if you have it or `awk -v OFS='\t' '{print NR, $0}'` will always work.

Answer (score 0):

Use tac:

```
#!/bin/bash

function process_file_backwords(){

tac $1 | while IFS= read line; do
    # Grep for xxxx-xx-xx number matching
    first_date=$(echo $line | grep '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}' | awk -F '"' '{ print $2}')
    # Check if the variable is not empty, if yes break the loop
    [ ! -z $first_date ] && echo $first_date && break
done

}

echo $(process_file_backwords $1)
```

***Note***: Make sure you add empty line at the of the file so tac will not concatenate the last two lines.

***Note***: Remove the awk part if the file contains strings without `"`.

Comment: Not sure about the commas in your `grep` pattern.  That would match the string `123456-1234456789-1234567890`

Comment: You see the grep digit duplication number {4,\} and {2,\}, just change them with the number of digits, for your example (123456-1234456789-1234567890) it would be ('[0-9]\{6,\}-[0-9]\{10,\}-[0-9]\{10,\}')

Comment: I'm saying your pattern would match more than just dates. `[0-9]\{4\}` matches **exactly 4** digits whereas in your example, `[0-9]\{4,\}` matches **4 or more** digits

Comment: Oh, that's my bad, I don't know why I missed that, I'll edit the post.

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about. Also, you never need grep when you're using awk.  `grep '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}' | awk -F '"' '{ print $2}'` = `awk -F'"' '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{ print $2}'`

Comment: That will be immensely slow though, orders of magnitude slower than just doing a single call to awk without tac even if the target line is close to the end of the file. It'll also corrupt lines containing escape sequences such as `foo\tbar`. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: When I ran it on the 100,000 line test file in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68245473/1745001) where the target line is just 45 lines from the end of the file the shell loop took 3.427 seconds to run vs using awk alone it took 0.056 seconds. When the target line was close to the start of the file awk ran faster still (but when you're down to 0.05 secs for the worst case who cares) while I had to kill the shell loop after it had been running for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

## **On MacOS**

You can use `tail -r` which will do the same thing as `tac` but you may have to supply the number of lines you want `tail` to output from your file.  Something like this should work:

```
tail -r -n $(wc -l myfile.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1) myfile.txt | grep -m 1 -o -P '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
```

- `-r` tells `tail` to output its last line first
- `-n` takes a numeric argument telling how many lines `tail` should output
- `wc -l` outputs the line count and filename of a given file
- `cut -d ' '` splits the above on the space character and `-f 1` takes the first "field" which will be our line count

```sh
$ cat myfile.txt
foo
this is a date 2021-04-03
bar
this is another date 2021-04-04 for example

$ tail -r -n $(wc -l myfile.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1) myfile.txt | grep -m 1 -o -P '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
2021-04-04
```

### `grep` options:

- The `-m 1` option will quit after the first result.
- The `-o` option
  will return only the string matching the pattern (i.e. your date)
- The `-P` option uses the perl regex engine which is really down to
  preference but I personally prefer the regex syntax (seems to use
  fewer backslashes `\`)

## **On Linux**

You can use `tac` (`cat` in reverse) and pipe that into your `grep`. e.g.:

```
$ tac myfile.txt
this is another date 2021-04-04 for example
bar
this is a date 2021-04-03
foo

$ tac myfile.txt | grep -m 1 -o -P '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
2021-04-04
```

Comment: I can't use tac on a mac. I need to use tail -r. Will it still work the above way?

Comment: @Ross I have updated my answer.  I don't have MacOS unfortunately so I cannot test it.  Let me know if that works out for you

Comment: Thank so much for that! Managed to get it to work on my end!!!

Comment: @Ross "Thank you so much for that!" means to accept the answer and possibly up-vote it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl` to reverse the lines and `grep` for the 1st match too.

```sh
perl -e 'print reverse<>' inputFile | grep -m1 '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}'
```